# Access monit running in Docker container from Browser

Tags: linux, docker, ssh-tunnel, monit

I have a Centos 7 vm running on windows machine. In the vm I have started a docker container in which monit is running. The monit control file `monitrc` has the below http interface settings:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
use address 172.17.0.2  
allow 172.17.0.2
```

The ipaddress `172.17.0.2` is the ipaddress of the container found by using `docker inspect` command. I have also tried using `localhost` instead of `172.17.0.2`. The container is started with the option `-p 2812:2812`. I have setup ssh tunnel in putty for the vm with below setting:

```
Source Port - 2812
Destination - localhost:2812
```

When I am typing `locahost:2812` in the browser I am not able able to access the monit admin page. Please help!!

Comment: Can you you try to `curl localhost:2812` from the CentOS VM to see if it responds? I would first try to eliminate the SSH tunnel from equation. Also, Docker containers networking run through NAT. That combined with the fact that IP addresses for containers can change means you should probably remove the `use address` line so that it listens on any address.

Comment: @AndyShinn Thankyou for your reply. I have tried `curl localhost:2812` and response was empty. Then I have removed the `use address` and `allow` from the monit control file and reloaded monit. Now I am able to access monit from browser by building ssh tunnel in putty as mentioned in the question

Comment: Here, the *allow* is the issue. it should be set to the IP of your CentOS VM mostly